# password stopped working

Tags: transactions, wallets, gas, fees, password

my etherbase password stopped working.  the passwords for my other accounts work fine.  I'm on windows, same thing happens in every version, 32&64.  any idea how this could happen?  is there any info I need to paste in here?  thanks

edit: it looks like I can't select a fee even though I have more than 1 ETH in the account, does this matter?  it says the same thing for other accounts, and those transactions go through fine. [image]

Comment: One thing worth trying was mentioned here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4153/52

Comment: yes that was me, I posted the question as a guest.  nope, no keyboard change.  I tried typing it into notepad and it's fine there.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your edit, and not being able to set a fee, there's a known bug that results in something similar which has been discussed in the past. [[Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-cant-i-send-eth-mist-0-7-2-osx-yosemite) for Mac, [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/how-do-i-keep-my-ethereum-wallet-synchronised-after-the-initial-synchronisation/4188#4188) for other platforms. I've hit the problem myself.]

If you're hitting this bug and your wallet isn't being kept in sync, then perhaps the same IPC issue is causing problems with interacting with the etherbase account.

See the previous threads for suggestions on how to fix it, but I think it basically comes down to finding a version of Geth and Mist that work together...

Comment: it's still sending transactions just fine from other accounts, and they also have a fee slider stuck at zero.  The blockchain is syncing fine too.